# Redeclare UI form component in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I've faced with a problem. I have to render price input type in the customer edit form on the backend. I have found that the price component has been declared in the definition.xml like this:

```
<price class="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Price"/>
```

So, I have created own definition.xml file in the view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_definition.xsd">
    <!-- Price elements -->
    <price class="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Price">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/price</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </price>
</components>
```

Unfortunately, XSD validation avoid this change from appling and I have got the following issue:

> Element 'components': Missing child element(s). Expected is one of ( tab, dataSource, paging, massaction, listing, form, fieldset, field, filters, columns ).
>   Line: 2

I have read the magento 2 developer guid ( http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-component.html ) :

> Any module can introduce its own set of custom components or modify initial configuration for existing components in a common to Magento way

Well, I have used "the common way", haven't I?

I would glad to read your ideas about this issue and ways in which we can reconfigurate the ui component via **xml declaration**.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will help so many months later, but `definition.xml` is where a UI Component's **default** configuration gets created.  When Magento uses a particular node in a `ui_component/*.xml` file, it users the defaults from `definition.xml`.  However, if your `ui_component/*.xml` file/tree, you can say

```
<price class="Some\Other\Class">
    <!-- some other configuration -->
</price>
```

and your changes in `ui_component/*.xml` will win.

Comment: I used wrong directory for my override, didn't I? Did I get you, Alan?

Comment: @RomanGlushko You used the wrong file.  You don't want definition.xml, you want your changes in the specific grid file.

Comment: @AlanStorm - Putting a new form field component definition inside a <form> ui xml file (for example), results in a "this element is not expected" error. Could you clarify exactly where we can define a new form field type? Magento's documentation is less than helpful, as per usual.

Comment: @AlanStorm - I think I understand now. You can only modify pre-existing components. You cannot define a new form element type altogether, say "customtext" for example.

Comment: @koosa That sounds right -- possibly of interest, I've been diving deep on UI components lately over on my site. http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2#magento_2_ui